# Connect из QVector<QPushButton*>

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Здравствуйте! Пишу игру и столкнулся с одной проблемой.
У меня есть 25 кнопок `QPushButton` в Ui. Я их поместил в вектор `QVector<QPushButton*> buttons`. (`buttons.push_back(ui->b1);`). Когда решил сделать для них connect, то решил сделать это через `for()`, потом через `foreach()`.
Делаю так:

```
connect(buttons[i], &QPushButton::pressed, this, [&]() {
    doIt(buttons[i]);
});
```

Приложение запускается, всё работает. Но если нажать на любую кнопку, то вызывается:

> ASSERT failure in QVector operator[]: index is out of range

В функции `doIt(QPushButton *but)` ошибку вызывает `but->text().toInt();`

А вот если соеденять по очереди из формы, то всё работает:

```
connect(ui->b1, &QPushButton::pressed, this, [&]() {
    doIt(ui->b1);
});
...
connect (ui->b25, &QPushButton::pressed, this, [&]() {
    doIt(ui->b25);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы создаете массив buttons[i] в том же методе, что и производите подключение и массив разрушается при выходе из области видимости. При срабатывание события нажатия на кнопку, выполняет:

```
 doIt(buttons[i]);
```

Обращение к массиву, который уже разрушен.

Можете попробовать изменить способ захвата переменных, чтоб они передавались по значению:

```
connect(buttons[i], &QPushButton::pressed, this, [=]() {
    doIt(buttons[i]);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)